# enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: Not Executed

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, block

Here is where I am calling it:

```
/**
 *  called when we are notified that a product has been purchased
 *
 *  @param  notification                the notification object calling this method
 */
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //  the notification object is purchased product identifier
    NSString *productIdentifier         = notification.object;

    NSLog(@"Product purchased");

    //  reload appropriate cell with checkmark
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct *product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSLog(@"Block executing with product: %@", product.productIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"Needs to match: %@", productIdentifier);

        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier])
        {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"Reloading due to purchase");
            *stop                       = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

However, the block is never being called, and thus the table view cell is never being reloaded. I can tell that the block is never executed because the log never shows up in the console. However, by placing a breakpoint I have been able to determine that the productPurchased: method is definitely being called.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have now changed the code above to allow for far more logging throughout it's execution. From what I have been able to gather by looking at the console, the notification object being passed in is the table view itself:

```
<UITableView: 0x1eaffe00; frame = (0 0; 320 704); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e57dfe0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e57da50>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

This is clearly a problem with the calling of this function, and so I will investigate further, and post my answer as soon as I have it.

For now I will include how this function should be being called:

**Signing For Notification:**

```
/**
 *  notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy
 *
 *  @param  animated                    whether it will be added in an animated fashion
 */
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //  add ourselves as an observer to product purchases
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}
```

**Sending Notification:**

```
/**
 *  handles all the extra work not that a product has been purchased
 *
 *  @param  productIdentifier           the purchased product's identifier
 */
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    //  adds the product's id to our purchased product ids list
    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];

    //  stores this purchase in nsuserdefaults for long term use
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    //  save the user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //  send notification to tohers for awareness of this purchase
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if _products is nil or empty?

Comment: Have you placed in `NSLog` statement inside the block but outside the `if` statement.

Comment: It's seem a higg bug-son. Do a test and try if you get an output of your nslog at the beginning of the method call. If you don't get it, then Xcode compile your app but don"t install it. You get somme old trace of your old version, and gdb will work. But i'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an incredibly foolish error:

The notification was being constantly posted, but not by the method I have included in the question.

It all resulted from the notification name itself.

I had been instantiated it in the IAPHelper.h class like so:

```
//  used to notify listeners when a product is purchased
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const IAHelperProductPurchasedNotification;
```

and in the implementation file (IAPHelper.m) I had been doing this:

```
NSString *const IAHelperProductPurchasedNotification;
```

when I needed to be doing this:

```
NSString *const IAHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";
```

It's odd that the notification was just being repeatedly called, but alas, it's hard to predict the behaviour of some of these stupid bugs.

Thanks for taking the time to help me guys.